# CRDs and manifestWorks in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I want to know how the CRDs are different from manifestworks in kubernetes

Also what if there is a CRD present in kubernetes and we create the same CRD again, will the second CRD overwrite the first CRD? Or whats gonna happen?  Same question of manifestWorks.

Comment: A custom resource definition (CRD) is a standard Kubernetes term; is "manifestWorks" part of some other product or add-on?  A CustomResourceDefinition is a standard Kubernetes object and reloading it with for example `kubectl apply` will attempt to modify the existing object.